# how to launch unity WebGL on browser

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I build on unity successfully

if I run and build on unity it works

but when I run index.html on browser from build folder;

first it has been blocked by CORS policy I created a chrome shortcut disables security

then I got

> Uncaught ReferenceError: unityFramework is not defined at HTMLScriptElement.n.onload

I looked into it and some said that to disable compression but I got more errors:

[image]

dont know much about webGL and not sure if its a problem on unity or browser

pls help

ps:my unity version is 2020.1.0f1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers won't load javascripts (`.js` files) from a file system directly.  You have to host them on a server.  Running the server on your local machine is fine (it's what Unity does).

Comment: cant run on local machine if not build & run on unity
if I just build it index.html is created on a folder I choose and when I want launch it on browser I got that Uncaught ReferenceError

Comment: Yes, don't open it straight from Explorer.  You need a web server.

Comment: dont know anthing about webGL but I can launch normal hmtl and .js files locally with no error is it bcoz of webGL?

Comment: It's most likely because of Unity's engine for webGL.  Because 'normal' security doesn't let you load js from file, Unity probably didn't include functions to load js from file in their code, only from HTTP.

Comment: thanks thats a relief :D
hope it doesnt have any problems when running on server

Comment: FYI, running a server is trivial. [here's a simple one](https://greggman.github.io/servez)